# Why is port forwarding not working in my network?

Tags: networking, port, router, firewall, portforwarding

I'm trying to enable port forwarding in my router (ZTE F660) but for some reason it is not working at all. First I started my server application in my ubuntu machine and I fixed its ip address to 192.168.1.2. Then, I set the rules as following:

[image]

It did not work. So, I've tried to disabled the firewall on my router settings:

[image]

It did not work as well, then I've disabled the firewall of my host machine by typing:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

And it did not work. Then, I tried to use many different ports and it did not work! :(

I've tried to use some port forwarding testers (like this one: https://hidemy.name/en/port-scanner/) and it always says that the state of the port is "filtered". I called the provider of my internet and they said that the port forwarding should be running but they did not offer technical help. Can anyone help me with this? Can't think about anything else to do.

Comment: You might want to try asking this question on [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) or [server fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: What are the first two octets of your router WAN address _Not_ what is reported from a "find my IP" web site, but what is on the router itself.

Comment: @RonMaupin Did not get you question! Could you be clearer? My router has a public IP address. The web site that I used was only for debugging. Besides, it says that the port is "filtered", meaning that something is blocking it(like a firewall for example). But I disabled the firewall on my machine.

Comment: What are the first two octets of the IP address on your router WAN interface? I do not know how to make that clearer. Many people confuse a shared address with a public address, and I just want to make sure.

Comment: @RonMaupin it is 100.64

Comment: That is not a public address, it is part of the [Shared address block](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6598) (`100.64.0.0/10`). You cannot port forward because your ISP is using CGN. Your ISP is using NAT, and you would also need to port forward at that NAT, but the ISP will not do that for you because others may want the same port. Basically, your ISP does not care that it breaks your port forwarding because your residential ISP agreement forbids you from serving to the public Internet. You need to get a business account to do what you want to do.

Comment: Humm. I did not know that. Would you like to post it on the answer so I can mark your reply as the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your ISP is using CGN (Carrier-Grade NAT) because your WAN address is in the Shared address space (`100.64.0.0/10`). That is *not* public address space, and it is defined by *[RFC 6598, IANA-Reserved IPv4 Prefix for Shared Address Space](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6598)*:

> Abstract
>
> This document requests the allocation of an IPv4 /10 address block to
> be used as Shared Address Space to accommodate the needs of Carrier-
> Grade NAT (CGN) devices. It is anticipated that Service Providers will
> use this Shared Address Space to number the interfaces that connect
> CGN devices to Customer Premises Equipment (CPE).
>
> Shared Address Space is distinct from RFC 1918 private address space
> because it is intended for use on Service Provider networks. However,
> it may be used in a manner similar to RFC 1918 private address space
> on routing equipment that is able to do address translation across
> router interfaces when the addresses are identical on two different
> interfaces. Details are provided in the text of this document.
>
> This document details the allocation of an additional special-use IPv4
> address block and updates RFC 5735.

The address block is detailed in Section 7:

> [7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6598#section-7). IANA
> Considerations
>
> IANA has recorded the allocation of an IPv4 /10 for use as Shared
> Address Space.
>
> The Shared Address Space address range is 100.64.0.0/10.

That address space is also found in the *[IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml)*.

---

What that means is that you have a home/residential ISP agreement. The ISPs are using CGN to save their precious public addresses for businesses willing to pay for them. The ISP NAT would also need to be configured to forward the port to your WAN addressing the Shared space, but the ISP cannot do that because others behind the CGN may also want that port forwarded to them.

The ISP does not really care that this breaks what you want to do because your residential ISP contract contains a clause forbidding you from running services from your network to the public Internet. You will need a public address and ISP permission to do what you want, and that probably means a business contract. The proliferation of CGN is a big driver for hosting companies, and that is an alternative way to do it.